# Reducing variance of estimator using sample variance?

Tags: estimation, references, sample

I want to estimate the mean of some distribution given some samples, but I would like to minimize some specific expected cost, where outputing a number higher than the true mean hurts me more than a lower one.

My estimator does not need to be unbiased, so I wonder if I can use the sample variance to reduce the variance of my estimator.

Intuitively, if I see no variance at all in my samples, I should be very confident that the true mean is close to the sample mean.
But if I see high variance compared to the sample mean, I might want to reduce my estimate.

Any hint as to what this is called in the litterature would be appreciated, as my google-fu has not been sufficient.

"Reducing variance of estimator with sample variance" returns results from the MC litterature about sampling procedures, common random numbers and using correlated variables, which does not seem to be what I am looking for.

---

Some specifics about what I want to minimize, and what I tried to do to make me think that I might need the sample variance.

I am not sure how to [directly optimize my cost function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/349544/reducing-variance-of-estimator-using-sample-variance?noredirect=1#comment658715_349544), given that I do not know what form $\delta$ should take - I don't have "parameters" to tune, so to say.

For independent samples $x_1, ..., x_n$ following some distribution $p$ with mean $\mu$, I want an estimator $\hat{\delta} = \delta(x_1, ..., x_n)$ that minimize 
$$
\mathbb{E}_{x_1, ..., x_n \sim p}[\frac{1}{2} \hat{\delta}^2 - \mu \hat{\delta}]
$$

The error made by the sample mean, using $\bar{\mu} = \delta(x_1, ..., x_n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$, is

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{2}\bar{\mu}^2 - \mu \bar{\mu}] & = &
\frac{1}{2}\mu^2 + \frac{1}{2n}\sigma^2 - \mu^2,\\
& = & \frac{1}{2} (\frac{1}{n}\sigma^2 - \mu^2).\\
\end{array}
$$

If I use a scaled version of the sample mean, $\hat{\delta} = \alpha \bar{\mu}$ for some $\alpha$ and try to find the optimal value for $\alpha$

$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{2}(\alpha\bar{\mu})^2 - \alpha \mu \bar{\mu}] & = &
\frac{1}{2}\alpha^2\mu^2 + \alpha^2\frac{1}{2n}\sigma^2 - \alpha\mu^2,\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha} = 0 & \rightarrow & \alpha \mu^2 + \frac{1}{n} \sigma^2 - \mu^2 = 0,\\
&\rightarrow & \alpha = \frac{\mu^2}{\mu^2 + \frac{1}{n}\sigma^2}
\end{array}
$$

I do not know the value of $\mu^2/(\mu^2 + \frac{1}{n} \sigma^2)$, but I though maybe it would be possible to estimate it from the sample mean and variance have, and incorporate it somehow.
However, computing the error becomes a bit tedious as the estimator is no longer unbiased if I use the scaling is not independent from the initial sample mean.

Comment: It seems you have in mind a special loss function. All you need is to formulate it in some form and then minimize this cost function.

Comment: @Royi: I'm not sure how to do that, but I might be missing something obvious. I added some more information about the specific problem I am trying to solve and where I am stuck in the "formulate and minize the cost function" part